# ID request, possible Hebe

Tags: identification

What is this plant? I saw it in San Francisco.

My mom thought it might be a Hebe, but I haven't seen any online that are very similar.

[image: Small blue-green shrub]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Hebe, and the nearest I can think of that's very similar is Hebe 'Red Edge' https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=912; although I'm not actually seeing any red edges in this picture, they tend to be less apparent in shadier situations. It's not growing in a very shapely or attractive way because its crammed up against a fence in the small gap between that and the paving or tarmac, but from its growth habit and flower colour, it suggests that particular variety. It's not the most attractive Hebe as it grows, tends to be rather gawky, just not quite so gawky as this one is.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain this is Quick Silver Hebe.  Gorgeous hebe, purple little flowers...the gray color as a mass of plants is to die for.  Zone 5 is as low as I would plant this guy.  What is your zone?

I've grown it in zone 5 in a protected courtyard.

Hebe pimeleoides 'Quick Silver'
[Quicksilver Hebe](https://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/3202/quicksilver-hebe/)

Note:  I just went to look at Red Edge and sigh, Hebe can be Red Edge Hebe without red edges.  This is Hebe albicans 'Red Edge' a little 'frosted'.  Kudos, Bamboo.[Hebe albicans 'Red Edge'](https://www.flickr.com/photos/88463529@N07/24774592935/)

Comment: Sorry Stormy! Its not Hebe pimeloides, quicksilver or otherwise - I grow that one here (and several other varieties) and its leaves are a lot smaller...as well as the flowers being much more vivid in colour.

Comment: I've grown this guy in my own back yard.  The flowers are fairly insignificant unless you are sitting in a lawn chair staring right at them.  Horizontal branching, usually only a foot to 18 inches in height and they change a bit from shade, to partial shade to full sun.  Red edge from what I remember was always very prominent.  This picture was taken close up sort of distorting the plant a bit?

Comment: Arghhh, note my edit to my answer.  Ugh.  I eat so much humble pie.